# Pipes between uncle and nephwew

Tags: c, pipe, fork

So I have the following code

```
const int CMAX = 1048578;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int fd[2];
    pid_t v1, v2, v3, a;
    if( pipe( fd ) == -1 ){
        puts("Failed to create pipe !\n" );
        return 1;
    }
    v1 = fork();
    if(v1 == 0){
        close(fd[0]);
        write(fd[1], "hello", CMAX);
        printf("v1      Parent's PID = %ld; Process' PID = %ld\n", getppid(), getpid());
    }
    if(v1 > 0){
        v2 = fork();
        if(v2 == 0){    
            printf("v2      Parent's PID = %ld; Process' PID = %ld\n", getppid(), getpid());
        }
        if(v2 > 0){
            v3 = fork();
            if(v3 == 0){
                printf("v3      Parent's PID = %ld; Process' PID = %ld\n", getppid(), getpid());
                a = fork();
                if(a == 0){
                    printf("a       Parent's PID = %ld;  Child's PID = %ld\n", getppid(), getpid());
                    close(fd[1]);
                    char buf[CMAX];
                    int bytes = read(fd[0], buf, CMAX);
                    printf("Message: %s\nSize: %d", buf, bytes);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs the following text:

```
v2      Parent's PID = 23859; Process' PID = 23861
v1      Parent's PID = 23859; Process' PID = 23860
v3      Parent's PID = 23859; Process' PID = 23862
a       Parent's PID = 23862;  Child's PID = 23863
Message: 
Size: 0
```

I want to send a message (or any sort of data) from the `v1` process to the `a` process. I suppose I have to close pipes in other processes but not sure how. I tried closing them in every process but didn't succeed (maybe I closed them wrong).

Comment: Why are you writing over a million bytes starting from an address that only guarantees the content of the first six bytes?

Comment: @aschepler That's a good question to ask. I changed that number to a reasonable value and it worked. Silly me.

Comment: @aschepler The bytes are allocated on the stack too. Ostensibly, the OP was trying to get his code to "Stack-Overflow™".

Answer (score 0):

As [aschepler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459640/aschepler) noted, I wrote way too many bytes to my buffer. So the correct version would be `write(fd[1], "hello", 6);` (or any reasonable value).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to send a message (or any sort of data) from the v1 process to
>   the a process. I suppose I have to close pipes in other processes but
>   not sure how.

You *should* close the pipe ends that go unused in your various processes, especially the write ends of the pipe, but failing to do so does not prevent communication via the pipe between other processes.  Instead, there are risks of deadlocking and / or failing to terminate, but your particular code as it now stands would not be affected.

I'm not sure what you mean by "not sure how", however.  Your code demonstrates that you know how to use `close()` and that you know how to use the return value of `fork()` to discriminate between the parent and child processes.  The only other thing is timing: make sure each process closes any file descriptors it's going to close only after forking all the children that need to get their own open copies.

> I tried closing them in every process but didn't succeed
>   (maybe I closed them wrong).

You seem to have some misconceptions about `read()` and `write()`.  In particular,

- these are low-level functions, and they know nothing about strings.  When you `write()`, then, you must specify exactly the number of bytes you want to write.  You cannot expect writing to stop at a string terminator.  Similarly, when you `read()`, you must specify the maximum number of bytes you are interested in receiving, and although you can transmit a string terminator over the channel, `read()` won't automatically supply one in the event that you don't.
- nevertheless, the byte counts you pass are *maximums*.  Fewer bytes than that may actually be transferred.  Additionally, read and write sizes do not necessarily correlate.  That is, there are no message boundaries unless you build them into the data you transfer yourself.

With those things in mind, if I correct your program to write and read exactly 6 bytes, then that is enough for it to produce the expected output for me.  That does still leave some potential issues around transfer sizes, however (short writes and short reads are not protected against).